# Javascript code only works in debugging Mode in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I've tryed to execute the next block of code, but only worked in Internet Explorer with the Debugging Mode open. I haven't added any console.log or anything like that. What is the problem? In Google Chrome and Firefox it just works fine without opening the debugging mode. I am working with the 64 bit version of Internet Explorer:

```
var validation = false;
        var val = $('#profilePicture')[0].value;
        var regex = new RegExp("(.*?)\.(jpg|jpeg|bmp|png|tif)$");
        if (regex.test(val)) {
            validation = true;
        } else {
            errorDialog('Extension not allowed', null);
            $('#profilePicture').val('');
            $('#profileImage').val('');
            $("#sicForm .bootstrap-filestyle > input").val("");
            document.getElementById('profileImage').src = "images/SAT-Placeholder.png";
        }
        var tgt = evt.target || window.event.srcElement, files = tgt.files;
        var uploadControl = document.getElementById('profilePicture');
        if (uploadControl.files[0].size > 2097152 || validation != true) {
            errorDialog('File exceeds upload limit', null);
            $('#profilePicture').val('');
            $('#profileImage').val('');
            $("#sicForm .bootstrap-filestyle > input").val("");
            document.getElementById('profileImage').src = "${ctx}/images/SAT-Placeholder.png";
        } else {
            if (FileReader && files && files.length) {
                var fr = new FileReader();
                fr.onload = function() {
                    document.getElementById('profileImage').src = fr.result;
                }
                fr.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there any errors?

Comment: No, I can load the image, and it shows it. But it is not saved or the file is not loaded